# How would someone brainwash a small group of people?

Tags: internal-consistency

I’m currently developing a story involving a small group of teens that have been brainwashed into thinking a select group of people are bad, so that when they are old enough, they will have no quarms ‘disposing’ of them.

What I want to know is how, historically, people have used brainwashing to control small groups without them realising it.

Comment: Step 1: When someone starts questioning the brainwashing, have random strangers on the internet comfort them, telling them that it's okay, they're not being brainwashed.

Comment: @Receilia It's okay, you're not being brainwashed!

Comment: When politicians utilizes fear or religion, they can package it up as facts which can brainwash anyone who doesn’t check those facts.

Comment: "Squad !!!  Ready !  Aim !   Fire !".  Job done.  Brainwashing not required, just army training. :-)  ( Army types - note the smiley ! ).

Comment: Not sure why this is tagged as off topic. [Understanding how the real world works is the best and frankly only option we have for comparison to what we are trying to create. Understanding the real world allows us to make alterations to reality in creating an imaginary world.](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6161/a-proposal-to-finalize-the-are-real-world-questions-on-topic-debate) @Recelica please make sure you amplify your question by providing more in depth worldbuilding context & criteria for what you actually want to happen!

Comment: I VTC'd as unclear because I A) don't see a question in the post, B) The only question that could be formed doesn't make sense (has 2 interpretations) C) both those interpretations don't match the title, and D) The question as stated in the title would be POB TB.

Answer (score 5):

This typical [cult behavioural manipulation](http://www.workingpsychology.com/cult.html). First, isolate them from their friends, family and the rest of the world. Tell them are apart of the Elect, a select group of an elite whose whole purpose in life is to carry a sacred mission or goal. The word 'sacred' doesn't only apply to religions, it can apply to any higher or lofty purpose usually reinforced by ideology 9another ingredient in the behaviour manipulation).

Cults are mainly dominated by a powerful authoritarian personality. But this can be replaced by a powerful dominating leadership group.

> A cult is a group of people who organize around a strong authority figure. Cults, like many other groups, attempt to expand their influence for the purposes of power or money. However, to achieve these ends, destructive cults employ a potent mixture of influence techniques and deception to attain psychological control over members and new recruits. This fundamental level of control is known alternatively as 'brainwashing,' 'thought reform,' or 'mind control.' A successful induction by a destructive cult displaces a person's former identity and replaces it with a new one. That new identity may not be one that the person would have freely chosen under her own volition (Hassan, 1990).

Many cults are identified as religious groups, but cults are limited to religions.

> > There are over 3,000 destructive cults in the US, with approximately 4 million members. They fall into 4 basic types:
>
> - Religious -- the type we hear about most frequently;
> - Psychological/Enlightenment -- offering expensive "enlightenment" workshops;
> - Commercial -- including certain pyramid and multi-level marketing organizations;
> - Political -- which are organized around a political dogma. Nazism was originally a cult, and cults can still be found lurking in the
>     left and right wings of American politics.

Sadly, achieving the objective of indoctrinating some teenagers into believing there is a group of people who they can and should dispose of is all too easy. The manipulative techniques and the organizations using them are commonplace through history and in the contemporary world.

Answer (score 3):

People do it all the time, you just don’t notice. How did Hitler do it? By utilizing their fear, say, their fear of being bullied, then you tell them that the “enemy” is bullying them behind their back. Tell them that you are their friend. Pamper them with gifts and compliments. Stage someone bullying them and then you help them. And voila, you have them brainwashed!